# Como posso remover 'R$\xa0' de um resultado obtido?

Tags: python, lista, int, slice

Estou coletando dados de um determinado site, onde ao coletar alguns valores estou enfrentando algumas dificuldades e gostaria de ajudar para resolver.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
valores = soup_anuncio.find_all('span', attrs='ek9a7p-0')
categoria_valores = []
for i in valores:
    valor = i.get_text()
    categoria_valor.append(valor)
    print(categoria_valor)
```

E o valor retornado (em str) é:

```
['R$\xa01.417', 'R$\xa01.200', 'R$\xa0185', 'R$\xa018', 'R$\xa028', 'R$\xa02.848']
```

Eu tentei tirar o `R$\xa0` do resultado de algumas formas, mas não consegui.

Como eu posso conseguir apenas os números em formato int?

Comment: Você quer valores monetários e int? Vai perder os centavos.

Comment: Os valores não tem centavos. Na verdade onde está o ponto é um separador de 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o objetivo é remover de uma string o símbolo de moeda brasileira e o ponto separador de milhar, itere por cada uma das strings pegue uma fatia do quarto caractere ao último para remover o símbolo de real mais o espaço e do que sobrar remova o ponto separador de milhar com [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) e então a converta para [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) pois como dito nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/502602/como-posso-remover-r-xa0-de-um-resultado-obtido/502609#comment928967_502602) os valores não possuem centavos.

```
categoria_valor = ['R$\xa01.417', 'R$\xa01.200', 'R$\xa0185', 'R$\xa018', 'R$\xa028', 'R$\xa02.848']

vals= [int(v[3:].replace('.','')) for v in categoria_valor]

print(vals)
#[1417, 1200, 185, 18, 28, 2848]
```

<sup>Teste o código no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/CXbwTP)</sup>

Aplicando no seu código:

```
valores = soup_anuncio.find_all('span', attrs='ek9a7p-0')
categoria_valor = [int(v.get_text()[3:].replace('.','')) for v in valores]
```